# Enabled Network Discovery on Server, and now VNC and Squeezebox clients don't work

Tags: windows-server-2008, discovery

I've recently setup a Windows Server 2008.  It's running an [email server](http://capesoft.com/utilities/EmailServer/CapeSoftEmailServerIntroduction.htm), [Squeezebox](http://www.slimdevices.com) server, MS SQL Server, etc.  I'm doing remote maintenance with UltraVNC.

I had everything working fine.  Then the server needed to access a network share on another machine, and I was prompted to turn on network discovery, which I did.  I chose the *Home* rather than *Public* option.

Since doing that, some things have stopped working, while others are still fine.

- Shared folders and the the Email services (ports 25 and 110) are still accessible.
- VNC (port 5900) and Squeezeboxes (port 9000) no longer work.

Here's what I've tried to try to solve the problem:

- Checked the network discovery settings, to see if anything looked strange.
- Checked the firewall settings, and those ports appear to be open.
- Also in the firewall settings, the entries for Private domain Network Discovery were all on, but the Domain/Public ones were off.  I tried turning those on.
- In the services, turned on *Function Discovery Resource Publication* and *SSDP Discovery*.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined some more details which changes the focus of this question, so [I've posted a new one](https://serverfault.com/questions/150052/one-workstation-gets-slow-access-to-the-server-but-others-are-fast).